# request.META does not contain header passed from curl -H

Tags: django, apache, curl

"It works on *my* machine."

I have a django app. I'm followed [this tutorial](http://ianalexandr.com/blog/building-a-true-oauth-20-api-with-django-and-tasty-pie.html). OAuth2 works great on my dev box like this:

```
$ curl -v -H "Authorization: OAuth c52676b24a63b79a564b4ed38db3ac5439e51d47" http://localhost:8000/api/v1/my-model/?format=json
```

My local dev app finds the header with this line of code:

```
auth_header_value = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
```

But when I deploy it to my ubuntu box running apache it doesn't.

I added the following to my authentication.py file so I could inspect the values in the log on the remote machine.

```
logging.error(request.GET)
logging.error(request.POST)
logging.error(request.META)
```

The header value is mysteriously missing from the output. So I just get 401s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you turn on `WSGIPassAuthorization`?

http://modwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration-directives/WSGIPassAuthorization.html

> Authorisation headers are not passed through by default as doing so
>   could leak information about passwords through to a WSGI application
>   which should not be able to see them when Apache is performing
>   authorisation.

Comment: DUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUDE!!!! ARHGHGHGH!!!! I have _NO_ idea why I couldn't seem to google something that turned this up. Thanks a ton. I'm happy and cussing like a sailor at the same time.

Comment: Ha...maybe it's the Brit spelling. #Authorisation. :P